# Equivalence of two definitions of the derivative of a real function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, definition

The derivative of $ x $ in an interval $ [a,b] $ on which a function $ f $ is defined is defined as..

$$f'(x)=\lim_{t \to x}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$$

**Why** is this equal to

$$ f'(t)=\lim_{x \to t}\frac{f(x)-f(t)}{x-t}?$$

Comment: You've just switched the variables. Which variable is used is irrelevant. $f'(b)=\lim_{a\to b}\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$, too.

Comment: But why are the derivatives at $ x $ and $ t $ equal? I'll change the phrasing

Comment: They aren't. Why do you say they are? The definition of $f'$ is the same. $f(x)=x^2$ and $f(t)=t^2$ also defines the same function, but $f(t)\neq f(x)$.

Comment: aren't they? So does the $ t $ used in $ f'(x) $ represent any set of points tending to $ x $? Or is it a specific set of points?

Comment: Review the definition of $\lim_{t\to x} h(t)$. $t$ is not even a "variable" in this expression. It is just a place-holder. The result does not depend on anything called $t$, only on $x$ and $h$.

Comment: I am actually trying to learn the definition:P I guess I'm confused what exactly $ t $ is?

Comment: In particular, while we often talk about limits "as $t$ goes to $x$," there is not actual motion involved in the definition of limits. There is nothing "going to $x$" in a normal sense of motion.

Comment: $t$ is just a place-holder in the first expression. It does not exist as a value outside the limit expression. Do you know the notation $\sum_{k=1}^n k$?

Comment: Yes, what about it? So does it represent a point that gets closer and closer to $ x $?

Comment: The $t$ in $\lim_{t\to x}$ is much like the $k$ in $\sum_{k=1}^n$. It does not represent a single value, but just a placeholder. Outside the expression $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k$, if you asked "what is the value of $k$?" The answer would be "There is no value of $k$."

Comment: I see what you're saying; what is it a placeholder for? I don't quite understand what it represents

Comment: Thomas if $ lim f'(x)=A $ as $ x \rightarrow a^+ $ is $ x $ also a placeholder variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $t$ and $x$ are just dummy variables, or placeholders. It doesn't matter what symbols you use to represent the variables:

$$\displaystyle \rho ' (\circ) := \lim_{\star \to \circ}\frac {\rho(\star) - \rho(\circ)}{\star-\circ}$$

It is usually best to use the same variable in the definition of the function as in the limitand. So when we previously defined $\rho$, we might have had $\rho(\star) = \text{something}$. But that's not necessary, and it usually doesn't matter.

Comment: that is p'(o) since that star thing approaches o

Comment: @randomgirl you are quite right! Corrected.

Comment: But $ f'(x) $ does not necessarily equal $ f'(t) $?

Comment: @user1961722 I think you're confusing programming and maths here. You cannot overload mathematical functions on different parameter names. It doesn't matter whether you write $f(t)$ or $f(x)$, as long as you use one variable consistently when substituting it.

Comment: Okay thanks, so what is the role of the star in this expression? I'm having trouble understanding what exactly it is.

Comment: @user1961722 the role of "$\star$" is the same as the role of "$x$" in the following expression: $\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \text{ as } x \to c$.